# Docker blocks incoming connections

Tags: python, docker, flask, firewall, iptables

I have deployed a simple Flask server in a docker container. The app accepts connections on port 7005 and I have exposed the port 7005 on docker. I can see the docker is actively blocking connections but I couldn't figure out the reason.

I have tried adding ACCEPT for DOCKER-USER chain for port 7005; changed policy to ACCEPT for all FORWARD; disabled ufw - but no way to access the flask app.

**The Docker run log:**

```
sudo docker run --gpus all -p 7005:7005 simplify:1.0

 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

**tshark packet capture:**

```
sudo tshark  'tcp port 7005'
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'docker0'
    1 0.000000000   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   TCP 74 43230 → 7005 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=153584425 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000052241   172.17.0.2 → 172.17.0.1   TCP 54 7005 → 43230 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
    3 0.003889881   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   TCP 74 43234 → 7005 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=153584429 TSecr=0 WS=128
    4 0.003934021   172.17.0.2 → 172.17.0.1   TCP 54 7005 → 43234 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
^C4 packets captured
```

**iptables policies:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running on http://127.0.0.1:7005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

You've bound the server onto the localhost binding in the container.

You'll need to bind it to 0.0.0.0:7005 in the container so it can be `-p`ublished.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that! Thank you so much :)